# Looking for a software keyboard for Android with better UX due to faster keyboard input

Tags: android, text-processing, virtual-keyboard

I am looking for a software keyboard program (layout and functionality) for Android devices such that the keyboard works as described in the 'Description' given below.

Simultaneously, I would like to know whether the behavior I describe has been implemented by anyone. I am also willing to give the opportunity to anyone finding what I describe useful and having the knowledge and ability to implement the described behavior permssion to do so.

#### Description

I'm using the Samsung Keyboard on my Samsung Galaxy SIII Android Jelly Bean 4.3 device. Under <kbd>Settings</kbd> → <kbd>My device</kbd> → <kbd>Input and control</kbd> → <kbd>Language and input</kbd> -> <kbd>Keyboards and input methods</kbd> → <kbd>Samsung Keyboard</kbd> → <kbd>Settings</kbd> I find "Predictive text" which was enabled by default (and displays text suggestions as you type which when clicked insert the text into the application text area widgets) as well as "Auto spacing" which was not turned on by default and I have had to enable.

With "Auto spacing" enabled, when I type text, and predictive text causes a few guessed words to appear at the top of the keyboard, and I click on one of these words, then when the word is inserted into the application text area widget and the word is not the first word, a space is automatically inserted between the previous word and the word just inserted into the text area widget.

Now, for the sake of example, consider the following use case:

- Suppose I type "ba" and the predictive text displays "bath", which, being part of the word I'm typing, I click on it to quickly insert the word "bath", but the full word I'm trying to type is "bathroom" which I did not select because it didn't show up in the list.
- So now I type "r", but auto spacing, which is very useful in many cases but not here, inserts a space followed by "r".
- Since to type my word "bathroom" I have to hit backspace twice after any insertion (and I could have typed any other character here in place of "r" including a space character which in the end is the fastest and easiest to insert due to the size and location of the space bar), to get the word right this slows me down by three extra keystrokes.
- Even worse is when the word happens to be made up of three, four, five, or more parts, any of which happen to be guessed by predictive text.

So, here is my UX improvement suggestion: Design a keyboard which uses predictive text as well as auto spacing by default, **and**, at the bottom of the keyboard, the space bar is divided into two buttons arranged side by side: the right-hand side works as a regular space bar, whereas the left-hand side is a special "Skip/Join" button to skip the space insertion and join the next word to the previous word. Hitting "Join" once just after clicking on any word among the predictive text choices appearing above the keyboard causes the space preceding the following character to be suppressed, thus considerably speeding speedy keyboard input producing correctly spelled/spaced words.

Is there any such keyboard that does this?

Comment: The way it's phrased, your post does not ask for a _software recommendation_.  Rather, it appears to look for help on a programming problem.  You should consider rephrasing your question within the context of seeking a specific software product, or, posting on another site.

Comment: OK, I think I've fixed the problem.